# Amazon Application Load Balancer wss to ws forwarding problem

Tags: aws-application-load-balancer, aws-alb

There is a target group in AWS Fargate cluster that manages node.js applications inside Docker containers. Every application serves web socket connections (web socket, not socket.io!).

There is a non-encrypted connection (HTTP / ws) behind the Application Load Balancer. However, outside it’s HTTPS / wss. Thus, when HTTPS request comes to Application Load Balancer, it decrypts the request and forwards HTTP request to a selected container.

The question is - how (and where) is it possible to configure wss->ws forwarding for web socket requests (there is a specific URL)?

HTTPS->HTTP rule does wss->HTTP transformation, which is insanely wrong. How to implement wss->ws transformation and is this possible at all?

Comment: Anyone? Great question...